# Spring Joda Jackson: DateTimeParser vs LocalDateDeserializer

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, jodatime

I'm trying to make Spring parse strings like "2013-11-11" to LocalDate.

I do:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers.LocalDateDeserializer;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

@Controller
public class MyController {
  public static class Params {
    private LocalDate myDate;

    @JsonDeserialize(using=LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    public void setMyDate(@JsonDeserialize(using=LocalDateDeserializer.class) LocalDate myDate) {
      this.myDate = myDate;
    }
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public void foo(Params params) {
    // do foo
  }
}
```

But when I issue request like "GET /foo?myDate=2013-11-11 HTTP/1.1", it tries to parse date using DateTimeFormatter, not LocalDateDeserializer, and so expects different format (I believe it's DateFormat.SHORT). Exception is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2013-12-11" is malformed at "13-12-11"`

How to make it respect LocalDateDeserializer?

BTW, Spring registers the DateTimeFormatter in org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeFormatterRegistrar, but don't see how to configure that.
Spring 3.2.5, Joda 2.3, Jackson 1.9.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason for Spring to try and convert your request parameter with a JSON deserializer.

Instead specify that your field should be converted with `@DateTimeFormat` with whatever pattern you need

```
public static class Params {
    private LocalDate myDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public void setMyDate(LocalDate myDate) {
        this.myDate = myDate;
    }
}
```

This annotation

> Can be applied to java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.long.Long,
>   Joda-Time value types; and as of Spring 4 and JDK 8, to JSR-310
>   java.time types too.